# Laravel 5 change base url route

Tags: laravel, routes, radix

I'm using Laravel 5. My site has url: 
"mysite/subfolder/"
But now urls are not working. They redirect to "mysite". How to fix that?

My routes are:

```html
Route::get('/page/{page}/', 'HomeController@index')->where('page', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

My link is proper:
"mysite/subfolder/public/page/7/"

But when I click it, it redirects me to "mysite".
How to add whole path to base url?

My .htacess file is:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        #Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are experiencing this after you moved your website to a host or something?

Look at this post on how to set this up:
https://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Comment: Yes, it's on hosting. Which way should I use? I tried second way, it's showing 500. I don't have paths.php file. This is about Laravel 4, I'm using Laravel 5.

Comment: the method you choose is depending on what access you have on your hosting. if you can go outside the www folder you should seperate your public folder from the rest of your app.

Comment: I tried it but it's still the same. I put in .htaccess file this:RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] but no result.